# React Native + Expo + Android + HTTP Server = Network request failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am trying to use the fetch API in order to upload in image to a remote server.
The server address does not use HTTPS protocol, only HTTP. I can't change that.

I've read tons of threads on SO and GitHub but I can't figure who is the culprit: React-Native, Expo, fetch API or the HTTP Server.

I've read that I need to set `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` in `androidManifest`. But I am using Expo in my project so there are no manifest files.

#### Where do I set the permission needed to POST images to a HTTP server for both Android and iOS ?

I am using EXPO GO on an Android phone for development: `Client version: 2.29.6`

package.json:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-animated-spinkit": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2"
  },
```

app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "lpr-android",
    "slug": "lpr-android",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "lpr",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-camera",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your image gallery."
        }
      ],
      "expo-router"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how I use fetch:

```js
const formData = new FormData();

const img = {
uri: compressedImage.uri,
name: compressedImage.uri.split("/").pop(),
type: "image/jpeg",
};

// Append the image to the FormData object with a specified field name
formData.append("image", img);

fetch(HTTP_SERVER_URL, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
},
body: formData,
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  if (data.error === true) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(data));
  setResponse(JSON.stringify(data.response.body));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("Error:", error.message);
  setError(error.message);
});
```

where

```json
compressedImage {"base64": null, "height": 1067, "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImageManipulator/0390fb75-3752-418c-a8c7-5e8837af099e.jpg", "width": 800}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this issue was provided on the EXPO forums.
I've installed `expo-build-properties` using `npx expo install expo-build-properties` and then added it as a plugin in `app.json`:

```json
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Seems like other people have also solved this problem this way: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16451#issuecomment-1489553710