# Expo Go Application does not work with HTTP but works with HTTPS

Tags: android, react-native, expo

So I am developing an android app w/react native Expo go and it will be only used by 10 peoples at a little place. Probably intranet. So I don't want to pay for a valid SSL certification but want my APK build to get my API calls obviously. On APK file that is installed on a phone calls comes when they are from HTTPS, but no response from HTTP. I am actually searching for the equivalent of when you try to access a webpage from web and it does not own a calid SSL, we click on advanced settings and proceed to this website. I need that but as a android manifest config, or expo go config etc...

this is my `app.json` file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "acme",
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ],
    "name": "newfolder",
    "slug": "newfolder"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native + Expo + Android + HTTP Server = Network request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090627/react-native-expo-android-http-server-network-request-failed)

Comment: Unfortunately not :/ @MorrisonChang

Comment: While not ideal, I think [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) does provide free CA certificates which would allow to have https for free

Comment: Unless I have to I better find a config and use HTTP since SSL providers generally want full access to server or they are time limited... Thanks for the answer though. @PhantomSpooks

Comment: [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) is not time limited and doesn't require full access to your server (https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/)